# How do I remove Dotdeb version of PHP and replace it with official Ubuntu repo

Tags: php, ubuntu, command-line, ubuntu-12.04

I'm a UBUNTU and CLI Noob.

I'm running UBUNT 12.04 LTS

I'm trying to get `CURL` to work for my PHP install and come to find out that PHPCURL does not work with the Dotdeb version of PHP that installed on my server.

Everything I've read so far says to remove the DOtdeb version of PHP and replace it with an official Ubuntu version however I'm not seing any clear instructions on this.

Is there an easy command to remove the Dotdeb version?

Should I just run `sudo apt-get -y purge php*`? I'm afraid that it will remove stuff I didn't intend to remove but I'm not sure.

Also, how do I know that the new PHP5 package I install is an official Ubuntu package?

Comment: Use 'apt-cache show php5-curl' to see which versions are available. You can specify the version of a package with 'sudo apt-get install php5-curl=0.1.1', replace 0.1.1 with the version of your repo. With that you can also downgrade the existing php packages. If the packages came from a ppa, I think there's a ppa-purge tool out there.

Answer (score 2):

First remove Dotdeb.org from your source list.

Next your need to uninstall php5

aptitude purge php5

Now run a simple update

aptitude update

Now reinstall php5

aptitude install php5

This really is the only way to go about it.  You really need to do a purge, because simply removing it using normal uninstall does not get rid of the dotdeb config files that sometime remain.

Comment: I also had to purge php-common in case anybody has that problem

Answer (score 0):

You might just not have the php curl library installed. `sudo apt-get install php5-curl` will fix that.

Comment: NO that is not the issue. CURL can't install because of the Dotdeb pckage. When I run `sudo apt-get install php50curl` I get the error `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-curl : Depends: phpapi-20100525
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`